# Visual studio Code, open current file in External Application

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write a simple extension in Visual Studio Code, the extension will simply take the current file and launch it in external application. How can we do that?

Comment: Considering that VS Code is built on top of Electron you can probably use **shell.openItem** to acomplish that. More documentation can be found here. https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/shell.md

Comment: @toskv shell is not defined in the vs console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer using [VS Code Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks). will appreciate if someone has a solution using extensions.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // we want to run vs
    "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe",

    // the command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    "showOutput": "silent",

     "args": ["/edit", "${file}"]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use anything that is available on node / npm. In your case you can just use `spawn` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Alternatively you can use `open` which I personally love from *foreground process launching* : https://www.npmjs.com/package/open

Comment: can you elaborate on how `spawn` is called from a VS Code extension? I'm particularly interested in how the child process's `stdin.write` function can be called after spawning.